# M2Crypto RSA Alternative method for read key

Tags: python, pip, rsa, pem, m2crypto

Actually i read a .pem file with M2Crypto RSA, all works fine but becase the virtual enviroment and the incompatibility of this on SSLv2_method on Ubuntu and Gunicorn i need to read and sign with the same methodology my code works fine with:

```
keys = RSA.load_key(archivo_pem)
cert_file = open(archivo_cer, 'r')
cert = base64.b64encode(cert_file.read())
xdoc = ET.fromstring(cfdi)
xsl_root = ET.parse('cadenaoriginal_3_3.xslt')
xsl = ET.XSLT(xsl_root)
cadena_original = xsl(xdoc)
digest = hashlib.new('sha256', str(cadena_original)).digest()
sello = base64.b64encode(keys.sign(digest, "sha256"))
comp = xdoc.get('Comprobante')
xdoc.attrib['Sello'] = sello
xdoc.attrib['Certificado'] = cert
return ET.tostring(xdoc)
```

I want change this

```
keys = RSA.load_key(archivo_pem)
keys.sign(digest, "sha256")
```

for a native method.

The key.pem beigns with

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MY KEY
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

All works on console mode, but when we try to run it on Gunicorn with Venv and workers the M2Crypto version fail, and it doesn't matter what version we'll use with M2Crypto always will fail.

Any advice for a native mode?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto/0.26.0 … SSLv2 problems should be gone (as is the method).

Comment: Solved! Seems like M2Crypto isn't compatible with Python 3.5 I use Python 3.5 on my venv i change it for 2.7 and upgrade the new version of M2Crypto for 0.26 that version fix on Linux the SSLv2 ISSUE!

Comment: @UlyssesMarx Help me to get a code review done on https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/merge_requests/65 … aside from the missing code review the port to Python 3 is done.

Comment: @mcepl Can you pls.take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928242/does-m2crypto-support-tls-ecdhe-ecdsa-with-aes-256-gcm-sha384 ? It's unrelated. Sorry for commenting here but wanted to draw your attention